# FFMPEG - merge 2 videos side by side

Tags: ffmpeg, merge

I have 2 videos, same video and audio quality but different length.
Lets say the video resolution is 1920x1080 pixel

I want to merge both videos side by side, considering the longest length.

**What I found so far, but it is not what I need :(**

```
On internet I found many examples which gives me the outcome of 3840x1080 pixel.
```

**What I want:**

```
Outcome: Video with 1920x1080 pixel 
use from video1: left part, such Pixel 1 to 960 
use from video2: right part, such Pixel 961 to 1920
audio is merged, i.e. I can hear both audios simultaneously as available
```

**What I want - optional:**

```
Between 2 videos, there is a visible split like |
```

Is there a single ffmpeg command line I can use?

Many Thanks,
BM

Answer (score 1):

using crop and stack:

```
ffmpeg -i test10.mkv -i test06.mkv -filter_complex "
color=red:2x1080:24000/1001:1[c];
[0]crop=iw/2-1:ih:0:0[v0];
[1]crop=iw/2+1:ih:iw-ow:0[v1];
[v0][c][v1]xstack=inputs=3:grid=3x1;
[0][1]amix
" output.mkv
```

or

```
[v0][c][v1]hstack=inputs=3;
```

if inputs have different framerates etc, you can try to use overlay:

```
ffmpeg -i test10.mkv -i test06.mkv -filter_complex "
[0]crop=iw/2-1:ih:0:0[v0];
[1]crop=iw/2+1:ih:iw-ow:0[v1];
color=red:1920x1080[bg];
[bg][v0]overlay=shortest=1[b0];
[b0][v1]overlay=x=W-w;
[0][1]amix
" output.mkv
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  

Solution 1: same  framerate does NOT work,  

v1) because "Option 'grid' not found" , 
v2) after 5 min high memory usage I stopped the process
Solution 1b: same  framerate does not work because "Option 'grid' not found". 

Solution 2: different  framerate  works perfect!

Comment: for old ffmpeg, replace `:grid=3x1;` with `:layout=0_0|w0_0|w0+w1_0;` and do not forget change framerate of color `24000/1001` to your fps